# Writing your own data source for spark.

Tags: apache-spark

We have our data in MS SQL Server, instead of using direct JDBC connection to the database we want to be able to push data into spark writing our own methods. In short instead of using the existing data sources API we want to write our own, Can anyone suggest some reference project that we can refer and build this.

Is this fairly a simple task or a very complicated approach we have in mind, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is provided by Spark out of the box:

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options( 
  Map("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver",
  "dbtable" -> "schema.tablename")).load()
```

See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases for more details

Comment: Maybe I did not frame my question properly. 

Instead of connecting to the SQL database directly, I want to write specific code which will fill the data frame. So whenever the call come to my application, I can retrieve data from SQL, then perform some domain specific calculation and then return it to Spark(Data frame/ RDD). Which is then consumed by end user by running queries on the data-frame.

Comment: DataFrame in Spark doesn't contain any data. It just provides a view on top of the existing data source (such as JDBC, file on HDFS, etc). The closest you can get is creating a JDBC DataFrame and then persisting it in Spark executors memory: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#caching-data-in-memory